# How to make a button that takes the user to a specific location on another website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a website and want to create a button that when clicked, takes the user to a specific location on a different website.

I've tried using code like this:

```html
<a href="index.php#firstdiv">my first div</a>
```

However, that only takes the user to the website, not the desired anchor.
Does anyone know what I would need to do in order to get the button to redirect to a specific anchor?

Thank you!

Comment: The way to do it is exactly what's already in the question. Does `<div id="firstdiv">`exist in `a different website` ? If the id is not present in the page source (on load, if relevant) then the url fragment won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `<a>` tag used with either `<input type="button">` or `<button></button>` tags.

There needs to be on the specified page your linking to (`armonkplayers.org` in this case) the following tag, otherwise you will go to the top of the page:

```
<a id="anchor"></a>
```

```html
<a href="http://armonkplayers.org#anchor"><input type="button" value="Test"></a>
```

Comment: Okay, so my question now is, how do I find the id of an anchor in Chrome for example. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Megastrik3 Do a right-mouse click on the page followed by a "View Source". Then search (ctrl-F)  for the string value: `<a id=` within the source. If you find tags that look like `<a id="xyz"></a>`, that would be anchor `xyz`. You won't actually find an anchor named 'anchor' in the example above.

Comment: Okay, so what I discovered is that the site I was trying to link to a specific anchor doesn't have the #anchor line in it, so that's why my attempts are failing. Thank you so much for your help though!